# RejectedExecutionException on Android - how to debug?

Tags: android, threadpoolexecutor

I got `RejectedExecutionException` on a specific device. I understand that the amount of queued tasks exceeds the maximum allowed and therefore the exception is thrown. I also understand that I can attempt to use `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR` to avoid the exception.

However, I'm a bit concerned that the app has queued up so many tasks. It is possible something is going wrong and duplicating tasks. What I'm after is a suggestion on how can I debug this and check the ThreadPoolExecutor queue and how is it filling up?

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25440): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.AsyncTask$3@c7102c7 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@27e100f4[Running, pool size = 5, active threads = 5, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 3]
```

Comment: "how can I debug this and check the ThreadPoolExecutor queue and how is it filling up?" -- log every time you execute an `AsyncTask` and every time that task completes, and see what the logs tell you.

Comment: So there's no way of getting hold of the default ThreadPoolExecutor? If I could query it that would help..

Comment: Well, sure, [it's `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).

Comment: If you can user Android Device Monitor it would be great.
Enable update thread option for your application;which will return the threads info; Also try to do profiling of thread.